# website is redirected to "https" in firefox(it is normal in other browser)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firefox, ssl, https

I am open my website in `firefox`, but because of something wrong with my website, url is force redirected to `https`(I think this is because I write `config.force_ssl = true` in `ruby on rails` application).

But after I redeploy another `ruby on rails` application, firefox still force redirect to `https`, how can I make `firefox` do not redirect to `https`?

Comment: _“But after I redeploy another ruby on rails application, firefox still force redirect to https”_ – that’s maybe due to an [HSTS Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) header send earlier. (And if so, probably not much you can do about it, until the specified time has passed.)

Comment: HSTS is more likely than caching as implied below; rails does send this header if you use the force_ssl option at the application level as the asker did. When I had this issue with Chrome just restarting Chrome made it go away.

Answer (score 1):

This is a browser caching issue.

Rails redirects to the HTTPS site using HTTP Status 301 (moved **permanentely**), the redirect is cached by Firefox.

Because the Host is always `localhost`, Firefox cannot differentiate between the individual Rails applications.

To resolve this problem try emptying the cache and/or use private browsing mode for testing.

I don't know about Firefox but in Chrome there's the option to completely deactivate caching for as long the dev tools are open.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear the cache. Firefox may remember http 302 - redirect permanently, and it does not know when you are using different rails application (as you probably run both on localhost:3000).